# PHP - retrieve name of script that included or required it

Tags: php, include, require

How do you retrieve the name of the script that included or required it?

Example: 
script login.php has a require_once('validate.php') ... validate.php is also called by a number of other scripts. Other than manually setting a flag, is there a way to have validate.php know which script is including/requiring it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];`

More here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: This answer doesn't get the point. The right answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598363/php-get-which-file-included-required-current-file

Comment: This is file that was initially called.