# PHP get which file included/required current file

Tags: php, include, require

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - retrieve name of script that included or required it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278757/php-retrieve-name-of-script-that-included-or-required-it)

Is there a way in `PHP` to get which file `required/included` the current file? For example:

#### controller.php

```
<?php
  include("add-person.php");
?>
```

#### add-person.php

```
<?php
  echo get_parent(); //should return controller.php
?>
```

#### Execution

```
php -f controller.php
```

Basically, something like the made-up function `get_parent()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I know of a "not so clean" way. Try going through the array `debug_backtrace()` gives you. Among other things it contains a hierarchy how the code processed through include files. Manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).