# Get the name of the including script

Tags: php

Is there a magic variable that gives me the name of the including script?

Example:

#### dashboard.php

```
<?php
include_once('test.php');
```

#### test.php:

```
<?php
// Prints test.php
echo ___INCLUDING___;
```

Comment: Sorry, no, there isn't. There is the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] information, but that is not the same.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278757/php-retrieve-name-of-script-that-included-or-required-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804539/get-name-of-file-that-is-including-a-php-script

Comment: Whenever I think I asked a nice question that gives me some upvotes, it's a duplicate -.- Yep, `SCRIPT_NAME` does not help in this case

Comment: Yes, but the answer from the second question does help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [an answer to Stack Overflow question *Get name of file that is including a PHP script*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804539/get-name-of-file-that-is-including-a-php-script/6804583#6804583):

```
<?php
    $trace = debug_backtrace();

    if (isset($trace[0])) {
        $includingScript = basename($trace[0]['file']);

        echo $includingScript;
    }
?>
```